# Rails, including more than one relationship in the scope of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following scope that returns all the products that have branch_id = 1, and also have the attribute enabled set to true.

```
scope :enabled_product, -> {includes(:products).where("products.branch_id = ?", 1).where(products: {enabled: true})}
```

Product also has a many to many relationship to Category. How can I include the categories for each product in this scope?

Comment: Why don't you just setup the relationship from Products to Category, A product has_many :categories, and just call product.categories on each product of your result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
includes(:products => [:categories])
```